# How to prevent client from sending an OPTION request before every GET?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Before every GET request client is performing OPTIONS request, is it possible to disable this behavior somehow?

Comment: that is part of the Same Origin Policy(CORS support), so I don't think you can disable it

Comment: Yes, there is. You can send it as form-encoded data, which will make some, not all browsers, not preflight the request with an OPTIONS request but simplest is still enabling the OPTIONS method in your backend given that you have control over it.

Comment: So, the easiest way to disable it - is in the backend?

Answer (score 1):

The OPTIONS request is being sent when you're trying to load resources not on the same machine ("same origin policy").

You could:

1. add a "proxy" script (i.e. PHP) on the same machine delivering the content that just relays your requests to the other machine. But make sure that nobody misuses your script.
2. use JSONP if you're fetching data from a JSON-based API. In my opinion, this is the best option.
3. change the script you're fetching that it can be used as executable code. I mean: make it possible that it can be added via  tag in the DOM and sets a variable.
4. you could add a apache rewrite rule in your apache server if possible.